# User ASP.NET runs under

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I'm a bit confused about how ASP.NET, what user it runs under? On iis 7.5 and on 6.0

A few of the user accounts that I'm not clear on are

- Network Service
- IUSR
- AppPool

Any clarification on the different users would be appreciated and security considerations/etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In summary:

- **IIS 5.1** (Windows XP) - it's a local `ASPNET` account
- **IIS 6** - by default, application pools run under the `Network Service` account which is a member of `IIS_WPG` group
- **IIS 7.0** - still `Network Service`
- **IIS 7 SP2 / 7.5** - runs under an ephemeral thing called `ApplicationPoolIdentity` which maps to an account `IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationPool` (e.g. IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool). This account is a member of `IIS_IUSRS` user group
- **ASP.NET Web Development Server (Cassini)** - it's obviously your own account

And it's a good practice to create a custom low-privileged account to run your application especially on PROD environment or when you need to access the network from the application.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.net by default runs underneath the [IIS_IUSRS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis-7/) user group. So if you need to grant permission to allow your application to run, use that group.

Comment: Thanks. Do you if this is the same account for IIS 6 legacy components? I'm trying to setup the pickup directory and not sure what rights it needs. In iis 7.5 they didnt' port this the SMTP service.

Comment: I'm rough on IIS6, but [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812614) makes it sound like IIS7 runs under "ASPNET"