# In which Account By Default ASP.NET 4.0 Code Execute?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Let's say, I have an application that access(read/write) the file system(files inside application), Active Directory and SQL Server Database. I need to give the permission to this account, so that he access these things. Application pool identity is IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4, Anonymous Auth is enabled(which is configure to IUSR), Forms Auth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below are some good links you can go through these to understand the iis user

In summary:

IIS 5.1 (Windows XP) - it's a local ASPNET account 
IIS 6 - by default, application pools run under the Network Service account which is a member of IIS_WPG group 
IIS 7.0 - still Network Service 
IIS 7 SP2 / 7.5 - runs under an ephemeral thing called ApplicationPoolIdentity which maps to an account IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationPool (e.g. IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool). This account is a member of IIS_IUSRS user group

Infomation source:-

[User ASP.NET runs under](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045641/user-asp-net-runs-under)
[What are all the user accounts for IIS/ASP.NET and how do they differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ)

http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/287/how-do-i-determine-the-security-account-that-iis-uses-to-run-my-web-site

Comment: So, which user you can it be IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4 or IUSR

Comment: Got it from here, http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729264/what-are-all-the-user-accounts-for-iis-asp-net-and-how-do-they-differ