# FileNet Api access rights for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, filenet-p8, filenet

I have some sort of trouble, but i can't figure out where it can be. I have a search method. It uses filenet api and connects to server using admin credentials.

```
ClientContext.SetProcessCredentials(new UsernameCredentials(login, password));
var connection = Factory.Connection.GetConnection(storeUri);
var domain = Factory.Domain.GetInstance(connection, null);
var store = Factory.ObjectStore.FetchInstance(domain, storeName, null);
return store;
```

At target system it works fine, when i run console application. But when i run it at asp.net web site i got
`"The requester has insufficient access rights to perform the requested operation."` error. Who is requester at this point?

Answer (score 1):

When you're running the application through a console, the user you are logged in as is used i.e. this is you and you probably have admin rights on the machine.

When you run it through IIS, this will depend on which version of IIS you are using. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045641/user-asp-net-runs-under) for more information. You'll either need to change which user the web site is running under or grant further permissions to the user (or group) that is currently configured.

Comment: I use IIS 7, I have AppPool with LocalSystem identity, what permission should i grant?

Comment: @Horosho, afraid I can't answer that as I don't know what the API is doing or the permissions it's looking for. Try looking at this link http://www.bluevalleytech.com/techtalk/blog/assigning-ntfs-folder-permission-to-iis7-application-pools/ for some guidance.

Comment: Thank you! Api is used for searching, but i can't understand, i use admin credentials, so i can do anything, but probably i can't connect using app pool identity.